# Parse: Get roles for an array of users

Tags: parse-platform

I have an array of users and I want to get each user's roles. For example, imagine my app displays a list of users and the names of their roles under their usernames. I cannot find any straightforward and cheap (without many requests) way to do this.

Comment: Sorry I'm not to sure I understand the problem. Could you explain the design of your parse database, so I can figure out what you are asking please

Comment: This question is independent of the schema since all Parse schemas have users and roles. Like I said, given a list of users, I want to obtain each users' roles.

Answer (score 0):

Query the roles.  In most cases this will be one, small query.

For each user on your list, search the returned roles' users for that user.  If you're searching on ID, you have all you need. (edit - removed reference to includeKey).

Comment: includeKey does not work for relations. I would have to grab each relation and fetch the list of users for each. The number of requests would be huge, possibly.

Comment: and how can I get the users ids? In iOS, a PFRole has a users property that is a PFRelation. To get the users I have to create a query on this PFRelation. Then, actually, I would have to make n + 1 requests (where n is the number of roles) to determine the roles of each user. Not a big number usually, I guess.

Comment: yes, thats the idea.  hopefully your number of roles is much smaller than number of users (and bounded).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a matchQuery. So from your list of users, use query to get all of user objects, and then use that query to get all of your roles. Once you have the roles, you can then match the roles to the users. I have gave the answer below for the Android SDK as you haven't specified which SDK you are using.

```
String[] userIds;

ParseQuery<ParseUser> innerQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
innerQuery.whereContainedIn("objectId", userIds);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Role");
query.whereMatchQuery("user", innerQuery);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> roleList, ParseException e) {

    }
});
```

Obviously you would need to fill out the userIds variable with the userIds of all your users. To be honest you could even use any other query for the users that would return all the users you want.

Comment: Ah you use an inner query. One problem though is how to know the role of each user from the roleList.

Comment: I haven't used matchQuery for a while, however I would imagine the user attribute will contain the user object?

Comment: Parse roles contain a users field that is actually a relation. To get these users I have to perform a query on the relation.